# vue3 component child property with typescript

Tags: vue.js, properties, components, vuejs3

This child property transfer does not work.

```html
<ProductItemView :productItem="productItem"/>
```

The code of child component is:

```html
<h4>{{ productItem.title }}</h4>
```

```js
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import { ProductItem } from '../../store/types/productitem';
    
export default class ProductItemView extends Vue {
  productItem: ProductItem = {
    id: 0,
    title: '',
    description: '',
    product_type: '',
    image_tag: '',
    created_at: 2000,
    owner: '',
    owner_photo: '',
    email: '',
    price: 0.0
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the property is not set from this parent component.

```html
<template>
  <div class="container is-fluid">
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
      <div class="tile is-parent" v-for="productItem in productItems" :key="productItem.id">
      <ProductItemView :productItem="productItem"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

What I am doing wrong? `productItem` is a property of the child component. And I call it from the parent component with `:productItem`.

Answer (score 1):

`productItem` is declared as a local data variable, which is not exposed as a public prop. The component template thus refers only to the local data variable, so it shows the default value of `productItem.title` (an empty string).

You could either move that to `@Options` under `props`:

```js
import { PropType } from 'vue';
import { Vue, Options } from 'vue-class-component';

@Options({
  props: {
    productItem: {
      type: Object as PropType<ProductItem>,
      default: () => ({
        id: 0,
        title: '',
        description: '',
        product_type: '',
        image_tag: '',
        created_at: 2000,
        owner: '',
        owner_photo: '',
        email: '',
        price: 0.0
      })
    }
  }
})
export default class ProductItemView extends Vue {
}
```

Or use [`@Prop` from `vue-property-decorator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-property-decorator/v/10.0.0-rc.3) (using the **`rc` version (`10.x`)** to support Vue 3):

```js
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';

export default class ProductItemView extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: {
    id: 0,
    title: '',
    description: '',
    product_type: '',
    image_tag: '',
    created_at: 2000,
    owner: '',
    owner_photo: '',
    email: '',
    price: 0.0
  }})
  productItem!: ProductItem
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I prefer the first variant. Is there any document about this and more?

Comment: It's currently only documented in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406).